# best time for propagation

Tags: trees, flowers, citrus, roses

My name is Nawaz Khan from Pakistan, Abbottabad. Kindly, tell me that what is the best time for propagation of Oranges trees citrus trees, orange sucker, and roses???

Comment: I would suggest this be split into two questions. One concerning Citrus, another concerning Roses, because I expect the answers might differ.

Comment: Welcome to the site Nawaz. GardenerJ is correct. You would get better answers if you ask one specific question at a time. Also, if you know what type of roses and citrus trees you're specifically interested in, that would help. While there probably is some generalization, you'll get better answers with any specifics you can provide.

Comment: Also, what type of propagation do you want to do? Grafting, cutting, seeds?